# CSS: Div Background Image position on eBay Issue

Tags: background

Ok, this will probably be simple to resolve, but I am a graphic designer & not a developer so wondering if someone can help me out. I have played around with positions but not such luck.

So I have a header div with a backgroud image within it, but when I preview the html/css on ebay the background image within this div appears at the top of the browser (conflicting with the ebay standard header) & not being positioned relative to the container div it is placed in. So basically the bg image is outside the div. I need it to be contained with the div I want it in.

Any help would be appreciated. (This may be a repetitive topic, so sorry about that)

Code:

```
<div id="HeaderContainer">
  <div id="BGHeader"></div>
</div>

    #HeaderContainer{
        position:relative;
    }

    #BGHeader {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        height:420px;
        width:100%;
        background-image:url(imagehere.jpg);
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
    }
```

Comment: Read up on CSS backgrounds and how divs work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post your html and css. At least the relevant parts. But having not seen them I would say my best guess is you're using absolute positioning on the header.
You need to wrap that in another element that's relative positioned.

```
<div id="container">
    <header>header here</header>
</div>
```

where your css is like so:

```
#container{
    position:relative;
}

header{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

If I'm wrong about your needs or situation let me know and I can update.

Comment: Below is your setup? You should update your question with the relevant code. THere should be an edit button toward the bottom of your post.

Comment: mate how do you post code I tried 'code here' and it didnt work. ha. Remedial I am.

Comment: edit your post, paste the code in, then highlight it and click the curly brace icon in the editor tools: {}. code cannot be pasted in comments. You will need to update your question

Comment: thanks for that, added to original post. So yeh - with that current code the background image still appears behind the eBay header, even though Other contents in the BGHeader div appear in the correct postion further down the page.

Comment: Have you added a background color to the parent elements to make sure your actual container is restricted as it should be? The code you posted should work as is, so long as you have <style> tags around that css. Also, see if defining the width and height of header does anything, even though that shouldnt make a difference

Comment: That did it! You are awesome. Just had to clear cache in browser for css. And bam! RESOLVED! Cheers

Comment: Another Question. Now I have resolved that issue;
How do I float another Container Div Directly below the Header Container. (The Container Div Below the Header is all Main page Content.)